# Pressing Left and Right shifts simultaneously changes the keyboard layout in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: gnome, keyboard, keyboard-layout

I recently updated my Ubuntu to 18.04, After the update, Pressing Left and right <kbd>shifts</kbd> together, changes the keyboard layout which is so annoying. I didn't change any setting and I checked my keyboard shortcuts, Just <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> is the shortcut to change the layout.

Answer (score 1):

I just stumbled upon this and not sure if this still is a problem for you but I figured out that having chosen Alt+Shift as a layout-change combination in `gnome-tweaks` was indeed responsible for the double shift change as well (turning it off stopped the behavior.) I however scrolled down a bit further and saw a separate key combination option - Left Alt + Left Shift. This one solved it [: